# Modify how Doskey macro passes arguments to the command based on arguments passed to it

Tags: batch, git-shell

I have a farily simple doskey macro

```
DOSKEY s="C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

So I could switch from command prompt to git shell by `s`

But sometimes I only want to execute a single command in shell and return to command line. For that I either have to enter shell, do stuff, exit. Or I could modify the doskey macro

```
DOSKEY s="C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -c "$*"
```

But that would mean I can't use it to do the former now, i.e *enter* shell, it's for executing *only* now.

I was wondering if I could have it conditionally choose between the two based on whether or not I have passed it another argument. So `s` would do the former, but `s echo hello` would do the latter.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use any standard CMD.EXE commands within your macro definition. The IF command can test if you have at least one paramater passed and branch accordingly.

```
doskey s=if $1. equ . ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login) else "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -c "$*"
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation of how this command works.

Comment: $* will put everything entered after 's' on the command to be executed.